# Fill missing diagonal gradient at the right and left sides of the browser

Tags: css, linear-gradients

[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qpd8f3t6/)

CSS

```
body:before, body:after {
    content: "";
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 20px;
    background-position: 0 0, 0 100% ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 20px;
    -moz-background-size: 100% 20px;
    background-size: 100% 20px;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #ff9933 0%, #ff1493 100%), -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #ff9933 0%, #3c4ed5 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(to right, #ff9933 0%, #ff1493 100%), -moz-linear-gradient(right, #ff9933 0%, #3c4ed5 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(to right, #ff9933 0%, #ff1493 100%), -o-linear-gradient(right, #ff9933 0%, #ff1493 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ff9933 0%, #ff1493 100%), linear-gradient(to left, #ff9933 0%, #ff1493 100%);
}
body:before {
    top: 0;
}
body:after {
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Attempted to set the diagonal gradient on the sides of the browser's viewport, but only managed to get top and bottom to show gradient. Wanted to show diagonal gradient similar to the diagonal gradient example.

[Diagonal gradient example](http://css3files.com/2015/03/09/creating-gradient-borders-using-css3/)

The gradient should follow like this image[image: box example]

How can the body be filled with the "borders" on all sides of the browser, including left and right sides of the browser?

Help appreciated.

Comment: How should the gradient on left and right be? Should it go from top - orange to bottom - pink (or) left - orange to right - pink?

Comment: @harry - gradient on left and right should follow in flow of color of the top and bottom so that it will look like diagonal gradient example

Comment: I don't think you can reproduce that diagonal border gradient effect with the gradients that you have and `background-image`. That diagonal gradient works in a way where you can assume that an element behind has a full body background and another element with white background is placed above it (or clip the inside part). This is not possible with `background-image` (unless you mimick what I said above). The closest you could get to with your current approach would be [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qpd8f3t6/1/). Or, another more complex way would be to find the mid point of the gradients and use.

Comment: @Harry - thanks so much for your help! the approach you did was close enough.

Comment: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/qpd8f3t6/2/) is what I meant by finding the mid-points (or to be more precise, the color at each corner) and then use it for the gradients. This is ultra-complex because you need to manually find it out. (*Edit:* Ok, I will post both as answer).

Comment: @Harry - I get what you mean. It looked complicated. Again thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagonal gradient created with `border-image` property kind of works like this (this is not the exact working but a sample to help understand how its produced) :

- A diagonal gradient is added for the entire body of a lower layer.
- The areas other than the border-width are clipped so that the inner part is transparent. (You can otherwise visualize it like placing a layer with white background on top of the diagonal gradient layer with height and width = height and width of container - border width).

The below is a visualization of how it is created. You can see that the `div` has the diagonal gradient whereas the `div:after` masks the inner part by using the white background that is assigned to it . If you can mimic this approach for your case then it is very good because this  is the **easiest and most recommended CSS method**. You could of-course use CSS or SVG `clip-path` to clip the inner part but the problem with `clip-path` is that IE provides no support whatsoever.

```css
.diagonal-gradient{
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top left, rgb(254,23,144), rgb(254,151,52));
}
.diagonal-gradient:after{
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class='diagonal-gradient'></div>
```

---

Because of how diagonal gradients are produced with `border-image`, it is almost impossible to mimic its behavior by using small backgrounds (which are the same size as the required border) and placing them on each of the corners. The closest you would be able to get without manually finding the colors at each corner would be the below snippet (but it is not exactly a diagonal gradient):

```css
body:before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  padding: 20px;
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-position: 0 0, 0 100%, 0 0, 100% 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 20px, 100% 20px, 20px 100%, 20px 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ff9933 0%, #ff1493 100%), linear-gradient(to left, #ff9933 0%, #ff1493 100%), linear-gradient(to bottom, #ff9933 0%, #ff1493 100%), linear-gradient(to top, #ff9933 0%, #ff1493 100%);
}
body:before {
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry-content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam at magna eu augue tempor viverra sed aliquam massa. Nunc odio velit, ultricies non feugiat luctus, aliquet quis ante. Nullam rutrum lectus non mauris commodo, eu imperdiet urna consequat.
    Donec placerat auctor commodo. Aliquam lacinia, mi vel consectetur aliquet, mauris neque elementum dolor, vitae volutpat massa elit facilisis lectus. Phasellus eget dolor ac dolor fermentum blandit. Fusce sollicitudin pellentesque augue ut tempor.
    Nam luctus neque et tellus lobortis, eget accumsan tellus elementum. Curabitur erat magna, scelerisque et lorem a, pellentesque consequat ligula.</p>
  <p>Ut a metus egestas, interdum est eu, hendrerit arcu. Sed tempus, metus sit amet tempor imperdiet, lacus nulla pellentesque sem, at pellentesque turpis mi non quam. Cras eu interdum leo. In non blandit lacus. Mauris nec volutpat arcu, sit amet porttitor
    mi. Mauris mollis libero vel enim tincidunt interdum. Quisque mi odio, blandit eget enim sit amet, faucibus gravida mauris. Donec fringilla faucibus gravida. Mauris imperdiet ipsum id posuere luctus.</p>
  <p>Curabitur risus leo, elementum a nulla eu, tincidunt elementum nibh. Ut eget sem at metus dignissim fermentum. Integer ac varius tellus, ut porttitor augue. Nullam venenatis congue ipsum, a sagittis lectus suscipit ut. Suspendisse sit amet tristique
    lacus, at rutrum enim. Aenean id dolor ac dolor efficitur molestie. Curabitur non sapien sit amet libero finibus vestibulum. Nullam sed odio mollis, rhoncus nunc vitae, laoreet metus. Vestibulum sed ante vitae sem pretium dignissim. Praesent lobortis
    sit amet libero eu aliquet. Suspendisse vel feugiat massa. Proin tristique lacus nisi, id laoreet ligula aliquam et. Aliquam convallis feugiat vulputate. Aenean sed lobortis nibh. Nunc erat orci, pellentesque et lobortis ut, ullamcorper vitae lacus.</p>
  <p>Suspendisse potenti. Maecenas accumsan eros elit. Sed non metus sagittis, hendrerit sem id, vestibulum nunc. Mauris vel tellus consectetur leo suscipit varius. Maecenas cursus augue nulla. Integer lacinia id mi in tempor. Proin hendrerit mauris at sem
    auctor interdum.</p>
  <p>Aenean vel felis a quam consequat gravida. Nunc non fringilla ipsum. Praesent interdum ante mauris, in luctus ex pellentesque vel. Fusce velit diam, maximus quis orci vel, maximus eleifend sapien. Maecenas nec mi aliquam libero tincidunt posuere. Maecenas
    eget sem id enim blandit viverra. Pellentesque convallis elit in dui luctus euismod at at tellus. Fusce ornare ex sollicitudin dui sollicitudin, id euismod mauris condimentum.
    <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam at magna eu augue tempor viverra sed aliquam massa. Nunc odio velit, ultricies non feugiat luctus, aliquet quis ante. Nullam rutrum lectus non mauris commodo, eu imperdiet urna consequat.
    Donec placerat auctor commodo. Aliquam lacinia, mi vel consectetur aliquet, mauris neque elementum dolor, vitae volutpat massa elit facilisis lectus. Phasellus eget dolor ac dolor fermentum blandit. Fusce sollicitudin pellentesque augue ut tempor.
    Nam luctus neque et tellus lobortis, eget accumsan tellus elementum. Curabitur erat magna, scelerisque et lorem a, pellentesque consequat ligula.</p>
  <p>Ut a metus egestas, interdum est eu, hendrerit arcu. Sed tempus, metus sit amet tempor imperdiet, lacus nulla pellentesque sem, at pellentesque turpis mi non quam. Cras eu interdum leo. In non blandit lacus. Mauris nec volutpat arcu, sit amet porttitor
    mi. Mauris mollis libero vel enim tincidunt interdum. Quisque mi odio, blandit eget enim sit amet, faucibus gravida mauris. Donec fringilla faucibus gravida. Mauris imperdiet ipsum id posuere luctus.</p>
  <p>Curabitur risus leo, elementum a nulla eu, tincidunt elementum nibh. Ut eget sem at metus dignissim fermentum. Integer ac varius tellus, ut porttitor augue. Nullam venenatis congue ipsum, a sagittis lectus suscipit ut. Suspendisse sit amet tristique
    lacus, at rutrum enim. Aenean id dolor ac dolor efficitur molestie. Curabitur non sapien sit amet libero finibus vestibulum. Nullam sed odio mollis, rhoncus nunc vitae, laoreet metus. Vestibulum sed ante vitae sem pretium dignissim. Praesent lobortis
    sit amet libero eu aliquet. Suspendisse vel feugiat massa. Proin tristique lacus nisi, id laoreet ligula aliquam et. Aliquam convallis feugiat vulputate. Aenean sed lobortis nibh. Nunc erat orci, pellentesque et lobortis ut, ullamcorper vitae lacus.</p>
  <p>Suspendisse potenti. Maecenas accumsan eros elit. Sed non metus sagittis, hendrerit sem id, vestibulum nunc. Mauris vel tellus consectetur leo suscipit varius. Maecenas cursus augue nulla. Integer lacinia id mi in tempor. Proin hendrerit mauris at sem
    auctor interdum.</p>
  <p>Aenean vel felis a quam consequat gravida. Nunc non fringilla ipsum. Praesent interdum ante mauris, in luctus ex pellentesque vel. Fusce velit diam, maximus quis orci vel, maximus eleifend sapien. Maecenas nec mi aliquam libero tincidunt posuere. Maecenas
    eget sem id enim blandit viverra. Pellentesque convallis elit in dui luctus euismod at at tellus. Fusce ornare ex sollicitudin dui sollicitudin, id euismod mauris condimentum.
    <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam at magna eu augue tempor viverra sed aliquam massa. Nunc odio velit, ultricies non feugiat luctus, aliquet quis ante. Nullam rutrum lectus non mauris commodo, eu imperdiet urna consequat.
    Donec placerat auctor commodo. Aliquam lacinia, mi vel consectetur aliquet, mauris neque elementum dolor, vitae volutpat massa elit facilisis lectus. Phasellus eget dolor ac dolor fermentum blandit. Fusce sollicitudin pellentesque augue ut tempor.
    Nam luctus neque et tellus lobortis, eget accumsan tellus elementum. Curabitur erat magna, scelerisque et lorem a, pellentesque consequat ligula.</p>
  <p>Ut a metus egestas, interdum est eu, hendrerit arcu. Sed tempus, metus sit amet tempor imperdiet, lacus nulla pellentesque sem, at pellentesque turpis mi non quam. Cras eu interdum leo. In non blandit lacus. Mauris nec volutpat arcu, sit amet porttitor
    mi. Mauris mollis libero vel enim tincidunt interdum. Quisque mi odio, blandit eget enim sit amet, faucibus gravida mauris. Donec fringilla faucibus gravida. Mauris imperdiet ipsum id posuere luctus.</p>
  <p>Curabitur risus leo, elementum a nulla eu, tincidunt elementum nibh. Ut eget sem at metus dignissim fermentum. Integer ac varius tellus, ut porttitor augue. Nullam venenatis congue ipsum, a sagittis lectus suscipit ut. Suspendisse sit amet tristique
    lacus, at rutrum enim. Aenean id dolor ac dolor efficitur molestie. Curabitur non sapien sit amet libero finibus vestibulum. Nullam sed odio mollis, rhoncus nunc vitae, laoreet metus. Vestibulum sed ante vitae sem pretium dignissim. Praesent lobortis
    sit amet libero eu aliquet. Suspendisse vel feugiat massa. Proin tristique lacus nisi, id laoreet ligula aliquam et. Aliquam convallis feugiat vulputate. Aenean sed lobortis nibh. Nunc erat orci, pellentesque et lobortis ut, ullamcorper vitae lacus.</p>
  <p>Suspendisse potenti. Maecenas accumsan eros elit. Sed non metus sagittis, hendrerit sem id, vestibulum nunc. Mauris vel tellus consectetur leo suscipit varius. Maecenas cursus augue nulla. Integer lacinia id mi in tempor. Proin hendrerit mauris at sem
    auctor interdum.</p>
  <p>Aenean vel felis a quam consequat gravida. Nunc non fringilla ipsum. Praesent interdum ante mauris, in luctus ex pellentesque vel. Fusce velit diam, maximus quis orci vel, maximus eleifend sapien. Maecenas nec mi aliquam libero tincidunt posuere. Maecenas
    eget sem id enim blandit viverra. Pellentesque convallis elit in dui luctus euismod at at tellus. Fusce ornare ex sollicitudin dui sollicitudin, id euismod mauris condimentum.
    <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam at magna eu augue tempor viverra sed aliquam massa. Nunc odio velit, ultricies non feugiat luctus, aliquet quis ante. Nullam rutrum lectus non mauris commodo, eu imperdiet urna consequat.
    Donec placerat auctor commodo. Aliquam lacinia, mi vel consectetur aliquet, mauris neque elementum dolor, vitae volutpat massa elit facilisis lectus. Phasellus eget dolor ac dolor fermentum blandit. Fusce sollicitudin pellentesque augue ut tempor.
    Nam luctus neque et tellus lobortis, eget accumsan tellus elementum. Curabitur erat magna, scelerisque et lorem a, pellentesque consequat ligula.</p>
  <p>Ut a metus egestas, interdum est eu, hendrerit arcu. Sed tempus, metus sit amet tempor imperdiet, lacus nulla pellentesque sem, at pellentesque turpis mi non quam. Cras eu interdum leo. In non blandit lacus. Mauris nec volutpat arcu, sit amet porttitor
    mi. Mauris mollis libero vel enim tincidunt interdum. Quisque mi odio, blandit eget enim sit amet, faucibus gravida mauris. Donec fringilla faucibus gravida. Mauris imperdiet ipsum id posuere luctus.</p>
  <p>Curabitur risus leo, elementum a nulla eu, tincidunt elementum nibh. Ut eget sem at metus dignissim fermentum. Integer ac varius tellus, ut porttitor augue. Nullam venenatis congue ipsum, a sagittis lectus suscipit ut. Suspendisse sit amet tristique
    lacus, at rutrum enim. Aenean id dolor ac dolor efficitur molestie. Curabitur non sapien sit amet libero finibus vestibulum. Nullam sed odio mollis, rhoncus nunc vitae, laoreet metus. Vestibulum sed ante vitae sem pretium dignissim. Praesent lobortis
    sit amet libero eu aliquet. Suspendisse vel feugiat massa. Proin tristique lacus nisi, id laoreet ligula aliquam et. Aliquam convallis feugiat vulputate. Aenean sed lobortis nibh. Nunc erat orci, pellentesque et lobortis ut, ullamcorper vitae lacus.</p>
  <p>Suspendisse potenti. Maecenas accumsan eros elit. Sed non metus sagittis, hendrerit sem id, vestibulum nunc. Mauris vel tellus consectetur leo suscipit varius. Maecenas cursus augue nulla. Integer lacinia id mi in tempor. Proin hendrerit mauris at sem
    auctor interdum.</p>
  <p>Aenean vel felis a quam consequat gravida. Nunc non fringilla ipsum. Praesent interdum ante mauris, in luctus ex pellentesque vel. Fusce velit diam, maximus quis orci vel, maximus eleifend sapien. Maecenas nec mi aliquam libero tincidunt posuere. Maecenas
    eget sem id enim blandit viverra. Pellentesque convallis elit in dui luctus euismod at at tellus. Fusce ornare ex sollicitudin dui sollicitudin, id euismod mauris condimentum.</p>
```

---

On the other hand, if you can calculate the colors at each corner manually (or use a color picker tool) then you could just create the gradients using those calculated values like in the below snippet. This output mirrors the diagonal gradient but involves manual process and is complex.

```css
body:before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  padding: 20px;
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-position: 0 0, 0 100%, 0 0, 100% 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 20px, 100% 20px, 20px 100%, 20px 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(254, 151, 52) 0%, rgb(255, 66, 114) 100%), linear-gradient(to left, rgb(254, 23, 144) 0%, rgb(254, 109, 82) 100%), linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(254, 151, 52) 0%, rgb(254, 109, 82) 100%), linear-gradient(to top, rgb(254, 23, 144) 0%, rgb(255, 66, 114) 100%);
}
body:before {
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry-content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam at magna eu augue tempor viverra sed aliquam massa. Nunc odio velit, ultricies non feugiat luctus, aliquet quis ante. Nullam rutrum lectus non mauris commodo, eu imperdiet urna consequat.
    Donec placerat auctor commodo. Aliquam lacinia, mi vel consectetur aliquet, mauris neque elementum dolor, vitae volutpat massa elit facilisis lectus. Phasellus eget dolor ac dolor fermentum blandit. Fusce sollicitudin pellentesque augue ut tempor.
    Nam luctus neque et tellus lobortis, eget accumsan tellus elementum. Curabitur erat magna, scelerisque et lorem a, pellentesque consequat ligula.</p>
  <p>Ut a metus egestas, interdum est eu, hendrerit arcu. Sed tempus, metus sit amet tempor imperdiet, lacus nulla pellentesque sem, at pellentesque turpis mi non quam. Cras eu interdum leo. In non blandit lacus. Mauris nec volutpat arcu, sit amet porttitor
    mi. Mauris mollis libero vel enim tincidunt interdum. Quisque mi odio, blandit eget enim sit amet, faucibus gravida mauris. Donec fringilla faucibus gravida. Mauris imperdiet ipsum id posuere luctus.</p>
  <p>Curabitur risus leo, elementum a nulla eu, tincidunt elementum nibh. Ut eget sem at metus dignissim fermentum. Integer ac varius tellus, ut porttitor augue. Nullam venenatis congue ipsum, a sagittis lectus suscipit ut. Suspendisse sit amet tristique
    lacus, at rutrum enim. Aenean id dolor ac dolor efficitur molestie. Curabitur non sapien sit amet libero finibus vestibulum. Nullam sed odio mollis, rhoncus nunc vitae, laoreet metus. Vestibulum sed ante vitae sem pretium dignissim. Praesent lobortis
    sit amet libero eu aliquet. Suspendisse vel feugiat massa. Proin tristique lacus nisi, id laoreet ligula aliquam et. Aliquam convallis feugiat vulputate. Aenean sed lobortis nibh. Nunc erat orci, pellentesque et lobortis ut, ullamcorper vitae lacus.</p>
  <p>Suspendisse potenti. Maecenas accumsan eros elit. Sed non metus sagittis, hendrerit sem id, vestibulum nunc. Mauris vel tellus consectetur leo suscipit varius. Maecenas cursus augue nulla. Integer lacinia id mi in tempor. Proin hendrerit mauris at sem
    auctor interdum.</p>
  <p>Aenean vel felis a quam consequat gravida. Nunc non fringilla ipsum. Praesent interdum ante mauris, in luctus ex pellentesque vel. Fusce velit diam, maximus quis orci vel, maximus eleifend sapien. Maecenas nec mi aliquam libero tincidunt posuere. Maecenas
    eget sem id enim blandit viverra. Pellentesque convallis elit in dui luctus euismod at at tellus. Fusce ornare ex sollicitudin dui sollicitudin, id euismod mauris condimentum.
    <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam at magna eu augue tempor viverra sed aliquam massa. Nunc odio velit, ultricies non feugiat luctus, aliquet quis ante. Nullam rutrum lectus non mauris commodo, eu imperdiet urna consequat.
    Donec placerat auctor commodo. Aliquam lacinia, mi vel consectetur aliquet, mauris neque elementum dolor, vitae volutpat massa elit facilisis lectus. Phasellus eget dolor ac dolor fermentum blandit. Fusce sollicitudin pellentesque augue ut tempor.
    Nam luctus neque et tellus lobortis, eget accumsan tellus elementum. Curabitur erat magna, scelerisque et lorem a, pellentesque consequat ligula.</p>
  <p>Ut a metus egestas, interdum est eu, hendrerit arcu. Sed tempus, metus sit amet tempor imperdiet, lacus nulla pellentesque sem, at pellentesque turpis mi non quam. Cras eu interdum leo. In non blandit lacus. Mauris nec volutpat arcu, sit amet porttitor
    mi. Mauris mollis libero vel enim tincidunt interdum. Quisque mi odio, blandit eget enim sit amet, faucibus gravida mauris. Donec fringilla faucibus gravida. Mauris imperdiet ipsum id posuere luctus.</p>
  <p>Curabitur risus leo, elementum a nulla eu, tincidunt elementum nibh. Ut eget sem at metus dignissim fermentum. Integer ac varius tellus, ut porttitor augue. Nullam venenatis congue ipsum, a sagittis lectus suscipit ut. Suspendisse sit amet tristique
    lacus, at rutrum enim. Aenean id dolor ac dolor efficitur molestie. Curabitur non sapien sit amet libero finibus vestibulum. Nullam sed odio mollis, rhoncus nunc vitae, laoreet metus. Vestibulum sed ante vitae sem pretium dignissim. Praesent lobortis
    sit amet libero eu aliquet. Suspendisse vel feugiat massa. Proin tristique lacus nisi, id laoreet ligula aliquam et. Aliquam convallis feugiat vulputate. Aenean sed lobortis nibh. Nunc erat orci, pellentesque et lobortis ut, ullamcorper vitae lacus.</p>
  <p>Suspendisse potenti. Maecenas accumsan eros elit. Sed non metus sagittis, hendrerit sem id, vestibulum nunc. Mauris vel tellus consectetur leo suscipit varius. Maecenas cursus augue nulla. Integer lacinia id mi in tempor. Proin hendrerit mauris at sem
    auctor interdum.</p>
  <p>Aenean vel felis a quam consequat gravida. Nunc non fringilla ipsum. Praesent interdum ante mauris, in luctus ex pellentesque vel. Fusce velit diam, maximus quis orci vel, maximus eleifend sapien. Maecenas nec mi aliquam libero tincidunt posuere. Maecenas
    eget sem id enim blandit viverra. Pellentesque convallis elit in dui luctus euismod at at tellus. Fusce ornare ex sollicitudin dui sollicitudin, id euismod mauris condimentum.
    <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam at magna eu augue tempor viverra sed aliquam massa. Nunc odio velit, ultricies non feugiat luctus, aliquet quis ante. Nullam rutrum lectus non mauris commodo, eu imperdiet urna consequat.
    Donec placerat auctor commodo. Aliquam lacinia, mi vel consectetur aliquet, mauris neque elementum dolor, vitae volutpat massa elit facilisis lectus. Phasellus eget dolor ac dolor fermentum blandit. Fusce sollicitudin pellentesque augue ut tempor.
    Nam luctus neque et tellus lobortis, eget accumsan tellus elementum. Curabitur erat magna, scelerisque et lorem a, pellentesque consequat ligula.</p>
  <p>Ut a metus egestas, interdum est eu, hendrerit arcu. Sed tempus, metus sit amet tempor imperdiet, lacus nulla pellentesque sem, at pellentesque turpis mi non quam. Cras eu interdum leo. In non blandit lacus. Mauris nec volutpat arcu, sit amet porttitor
    mi. Mauris mollis libero vel enim tincidunt interdum. Quisque mi odio, blandit eget enim sit amet, faucibus gravida mauris. Donec fringilla faucibus gravida. Mauris imperdiet ipsum id posuere luctus.</p>
  <p>Curabitur risus leo, elementum a nulla eu, tincidunt elementum nibh. Ut eget sem at metus dignissim fermentum. Integer ac varius tellus, ut porttitor augue. Nullam venenatis congue ipsum, a sagittis lectus suscipit ut. Suspendisse sit amet tristique
    lacus, at rutrum enim. Aenean id dolor ac dolor efficitur molestie. Curabitur non sapien sit amet libero finibus vestibulum. Nullam sed odio mollis, rhoncus nunc vitae, laoreet metus. Vestibulum sed ante vitae sem pretium dignissim. Praesent lobortis
    sit amet libero eu aliquet. Suspendisse vel feugiat massa. Proin tristique lacus nisi, id laoreet ligula aliquam et. Aliquam convallis feugiat vulputate. Aenean sed lobortis nibh. Nunc erat orci, pellentesque et lobortis ut, ullamcorper vitae lacus.</p>
  <p>Suspendisse potenti. Maecenas accumsan eros elit. Sed non metus sagittis, hendrerit sem id, vestibulum nunc. Mauris vel tellus consectetur leo suscipit varius. Maecenas cursus augue nulla. Integer lacinia id mi in tempor. Proin hendrerit mauris at sem
    auctor interdum.</p>
  <p>Aenean vel felis a quam consequat gravida. Nunc non fringilla ipsum. Praesent interdum ante mauris, in luctus ex pellentesque vel. Fusce velit diam, maximus quis orci vel, maximus eleifend sapien. Maecenas nec mi aliquam libero tincidunt posuere. Maecenas
    eget sem id enim blandit viverra. Pellentesque convallis elit in dui luctus euismod at at tellus. Fusce ornare ex sollicitudin dui sollicitudin, id euismod mauris condimentum.
    <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam at magna eu augue tempor viverra sed aliquam massa. Nunc odio velit, ultricies non feugiat luctus, aliquet quis ante. Nullam rutrum lectus non mauris commodo, eu imperdiet urna consequat.
    Donec placerat auctor commodo. Aliquam lacinia, mi vel consectetur aliquet, mauris neque elementum dolor, vitae volutpat massa elit facilisis lectus. Phasellus eget dolor ac dolor fermentum blandit. Fusce sollicitudin pellentesque augue ut tempor.
    Nam luctus neque et tellus lobortis, eget accumsan tellus elementum. Curabitur erat magna, scelerisque et lorem a, pellentesque consequat ligula.</p>
  <p>Ut a metus egestas, interdum est eu, hendrerit arcu. Sed tempus, metus sit amet tempor imperdiet, lacus nulla pellentesque sem, at pellentesque turpis mi non quam. Cras eu interdum leo. In non blandit lacus. Mauris nec volutpat arcu, sit amet porttitor
    mi. Mauris mollis libero vel enim tincidunt interdum. Quisque mi odio, blandit eget enim sit amet, faucibus gravida mauris. Donec fringilla faucibus gravida. Mauris imperdiet ipsum id posuere luctus.</p>
  <p>Curabitur risus leo, elementum a nulla eu, tincidunt elementum nibh. Ut eget sem at metus dignissim fermentum. Integer ac varius tellus, ut porttitor augue. Nullam venenatis congue ipsum, a sagittis lectus suscipit ut. Suspendisse sit amet tristique
    lacus, at rutrum enim. Aenean id dolor ac dolor efficitur molestie. Curabitur non sapien sit amet libero finibus vestibulum. Nullam sed odio mollis, rhoncus nunc vitae, laoreet metus. Vestibulum sed ante vitae sem pretium dignissim. Praesent lobortis
    sit amet libero eu aliquet. Suspendisse vel feugiat massa. Proin tristique lacus nisi, id laoreet ligula aliquam et. Aliquam convallis feugiat vulputate. Aenean sed lobortis nibh. Nunc erat orci, pellentesque et lobortis ut, ullamcorper vitae lacus.</p>
  <p>Suspendisse potenti. Maecenas accumsan eros elit. Sed non metus sagittis, hendrerit sem id, vestibulum nunc. Mauris vel tellus consectetur leo suscipit varius. Maecenas cursus augue nulla. Integer lacinia id mi in tempor. Proin hendrerit mauris at sem
    auctor interdum.</p>
  <p>Aenean vel felis a quam consequat gravida. Nunc non fringilla ipsum. Praesent interdum ante mauris, in luctus ex pellentesque vel. Fusce velit diam, maximus quis orci vel, maximus eleifend sapien. Maecenas nec mi aliquam libero tincidunt posuere. Maecenas
    eget sem id enim blandit viverra. Pellentesque convallis elit in dui luctus euismod at at tellus. Fusce ornare ex sollicitudin dui sollicitudin, id euismod mauris condimentum.</p>
```

Comment: my apologies - I test with a href tag in the content and it seems not to be clickable? Is it because of the position: fixed?

Comment: Didn't get you. You mean the gradient is assigned to an anchor tag? I am not sure if the `position: fixed` affects it but I could maybe suggest a different solution if you explain your exact use case. Generally gradients are part of the element and so would respond to click events.

Comment: no, I mean I wanted to have a link for example navigation inside the content along with lorem and it cant be clicked at all. the example - [link](http://jsfiddle.net/qpd8f3t6/3/)

Comment: yeah I tried also with z-index. will test with different div for only gradient. thanks

Comment: @joe: That's because the `after` element is on top of the contents and so the link is inaccessible. I tried setting `z-index: -1` but it kind of makes the content come over the gradient. So you need to add `pointer-events: none` to the `body:after` like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qpd8f3t6/4/). If you are satisfied with the answer, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: tried to put pointer-events: none on the a links but it didn't work. Thank you very much!

Comment: @joe: No, you should put it on the pseudo element which has the gradient (like in my demo) and not on the anchors.

Comment: yes i tried before I saw your comment. Thanks very much.